# Javascript redirect from alert box

Tags: javascript, redirect, alert

Hi I have an alert box that gets called using javascript, I want to redirect to the users_signup page when someone clicks ok on the alert box how can I do this is it like this?

```
alert("You need to sign in to be able to vote");
   redirect_to sign_up_url
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (confirm("You need to sign in to be able to vote")){
   // They have clicked OK
   window.location = 'http://website.com/sign_up_url';
}
```

Or, to force the redirect after the alert box has popped up:

```
alert("You need to sign in to be able to vote");
// The code execution won't proceed until they click OK
window.location = 'http://website.com/sign_up_url';
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way you do that with just an alert box, because I don't want them to have the option to click cancel and stay on the current page

Comment: @user2527785 Yup, I've added that to my answer